# jQuery toggle next and previous li

Tags: jquery, hide, toggle, show, html-lists

I have this problem with toggling the next and previous li element.

Current I can show only 1 element, how can I modify it to make it toggle 3 or any n elements instead

I have the code over here http://jsfiddle.net/DUXN7/

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

may be something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Jeumv/2/
looping logic is up to you...